# AppleScript app is not recognized as default browser

Tags: applescript, catalina, defaults

**Target OS:** Macos 10.15.3 Catalina

**Goal:** use apple script bundled to app as a default web browser

To debug I'm using very simple apple script, that just show passed url in dialog

```
on open location theURL
    display dialog "Passed url : " & theURL
end open location
```

I also added `CFBundleURLTypes` to Info.plist to claim binding to http\https url schemas

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>My test app url</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>http</string>
                <string>https</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

**The problem:** is that app is not showing up in 'Default web browser' combobox in System Preferences -> General

I've tried to dump Launch Service database 
`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump`

And my app is present there.

Also tried force register
`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f ./MyTestApp.app`

Also tried to sign my app by self issued signature.

Nothing helped.

**What could I miss?** Is there any additional configurations that should be done to let macos recognize my apple scrip app as possible default browser?

Comment: Have you run your app ?  That is, did you save it, then double-click on it the `.app` bundle ?

Comment: Of course I've have run it. And as I mentioned it was registered in Launch Service database, i.e. I see my app in its dump. In other words macos is aware of my application but for some reason not allow to choose it as a default browser

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm on Ventura and I've just done something similar that successfully handles `mailto` links but I don't seem to be able to make it work for `http`/`https` 

Comment: *Update* It just started working for me. Like you it was showing up in Launch Services but not the browser chooser. To test the app standalone I removed the "on open location theURL" block and saved it. When I added it back in and saved it again it immediately showed up in the list of available browsers and started working ‍♂️ If that works for you too I can try and write it up as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can build a browser like that, but I do know that there is a very simple browser out that which will take whatever URL it is sent and pass it to the clipboard:

https://github.com/alistairmcmillan/short/tree/master/Copy%20URL%20to%20Clipboard

Perhaps that might help.

Comment: I don't wanna build a browser I want an app that can be assigned as default handler for http\https url schemas. As I understand the app build from apple script is just an app as many others and I don't see any reason why it can't be a default handler for http\https. As I can judge app shouldn't be a real browser to be selected as default browser(just because I can choose evernote app, video player, or even iTerm as a default browser(i.e. default handler for http)). Looks like the matter in configuration. Therefore the question is how properly configure my app.

Comment: I understand what you want. What I'm saying is that I don't think it can be done the way that you want it to be done. I'd be happy to be proven wrong, but I've never seen anything that suggests that what you want can be done the way you want to do it. All of the examples that you give are…apps… not AppleScript wrappers exported as an app.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t guarantee this, but here’s what I would try:

1. Create a .webloc on the desktop, pointing to any URI.
2. Select it, Get Info, and change its application to your desired default.  You’ll have to change “suggested apps” to “other” to be able to do it.
3. Check the box to do it for all files of this type.

Comment: It won't help since it set default application for .webloc file type not for http\https url schemas, what is originally desired

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by also adding document types for **HTML** and **XHTML** to the Info.plist, like this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>HTML document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.html</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>XHTML document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.xhtml</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Web site URL</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>http</string>
            <string>https</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Your answer would be so much more useful if you'd add additional information on explicitly and specifically how/what to do with what you posted. Please consider improving your answer by editing in the missing information.

Comment: @user3439894 the information is already there, maybe is not clear enough?; this is what I added to the Info.plist file in order to be selectable for Default browser.

Comment: You have missed the point entirely! You should provide the information and steps necessary to actually add it to the Info.plist _file_. This includes where the file resides and how to edit it so as not to damage it!